# Determine transformation matrix from quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V=\mathbb R^3$. Consider the quadratic form $$q:V\to\mathbb R, (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T\rightarrow 5x_1^2+5x_2^2-4x_3^2-14x_1x_2+4x_1x_3+4x_2x_3$$

And let $\beta:V \times V\to \mathbb R$ the symmetric form which has $q$ as quadratic form.

With polarisation, i.e. $\beta(v,w)=\frac12(q(v+w)-q(v)-q(w))$ I calculated the transformation matrix of $\beta$ wrt to the standard basis B, i.e. $[\beta]_{B\times B}=$ $
 \begin{bmatrix}
5 & -7 & 2  \\
-7 & 5 & 2  \\
2 & 2 & -4 
\end{bmatrix}
$.

> Now I want to determine a basis $\cal B$ such that $[\beta]_{\cal B \times \cal B}=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0  \\
> 0 & -1 & 0  \\
> 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$.

I tried to consider $\beta(b_1,b_1)=1 $ and $\beta(b_2,b_2)=-1$, but I do not see how to proceed, it is getting really messy. How should one handle this task?

Comment: first calculate the diagonalization of the matrix and then use sylvester’s  law of inertia for matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added: the cleanest expression before reaching the $\pm 1$ stage is
$$ 8\left(2x - y - z \right)^2  - 3\left(3x - y - 2z \right)^2 = 5 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 4 z^2 + 4 yz + 4 zx - 14 xy.$$ This becomes
$$ \left( \sqrt {32} \;x - \sqrt 8 \; y - \sqrt 8 \; z \right)^2  - \left( \sqrt {27} \;x - \sqrt 3 \; y - \sqrt {12} \;z \right)^2 = 5 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 4 z^2 + 4 yz + 4 zx - 14 xy.$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 7 & 2 \\ 
 - 7 & 5 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 7 & 2 \\ 
 - 7 & 5 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

At this stage, to force diagonal elements to be $\pm 1,$ we will need to introduce some square roots, but we can throw these in a diagonal matrix that is its own transpose $S^T = S, \; \; $ let us call it $S$ for square root,
$$
S =
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 5} & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &    \frac{\sqrt 5}{ \sqrt{24} }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
so that 
$$ S^T D S =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 $$

Finally
$$ S^T P^T H P S =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 $$

and your basis matrix is $R = PS$

---

The algorithm for the first part, all rational entries, is:

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 7 & 2 \\ 
 - 7 & 5 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 7 & 2 \\ 
 - 7 & 5 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  \\ 
2 &  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 7 & 2 \\ 
 - 7 & 5 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 7 & 2 \\ 
 - 7 & 5 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: wow! Thanks for this huge amount of afford!